# Buildr - Exclude source files when compiling

Tags: ruby, rake, buildr

Is there a way to exclude certain packages or source files when compiling in buildr? There isn't an exclude on the compile task as it looks in the src directory. We are building for multiple environments and for one of the environments we need to exclude a few source files otherwise it won't compile.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: To get around this problem I just moved the env specific source files into their own project. Still would be interesting to know if there is a way to exclude source files when compiling

Answer (score 2):

`compile.sources` only contains the source directories and there is no way to tell buildr to exclude subdirectories directly from that. However, before compilation, buildr lists all the files in these directories to pass them on to the compiler (you can see this with `buildr --trace compile`). You could monkey-patch `Buildr::Compiler::Base::files_from_sources` to exclude some stuff, but that seems way too intrusive.

---

I would turn the problem upside down: instead of putting all the code in a single source directory, put environment-specific stuff in its own directory like so:

```
src/main/java
src/other-env/java
```

Most if not all IDEs support multiple source directories, so that should not be a problem.

Then define buildr projects for each of the environments by adding the appropriate source directory to the compilation path using `compile.from` (same for resources). If `src/main/java` compiles on its own, you could also separate that into its own project and have the others depend on it, thus avoiding having to recompile it over and over.

To make the build script simpler, think about making the various environments proper [sub-projects](https://buildr.apache.org/projects.html#dir_structure).